# What part of speech is (red)?

Tags: adjectives, parts-of-speech, object-complements

Is the word (red) in this sentence an adjective modifying the noun (leaves)

Or (red) is a common noun functions as an object complement. ?

> Pigments turn the leaves **red**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Pigments turn the leaves red.

No, *red* is not a noun in your example.  It is an object complement functioning as adjective modifying the noun *leaves*.

[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_complement) has an example very similar to yours.

> She painted the barn red. – Adjective as object complement

> [A]n object complement is a predicative expression that follows a direct object of an attributive ditransitive verb or resultative verb and that complements the direct object of the sentence by describing it.